# spring cloud dataflow unable to restart a Spring batch job where it left off

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am running a spring batch job via spring cloud task on my local spring cloud dataflow server (single node) for reading data from the source system database and writing into Kafka. When my task/job failed in the middle of the execution, I am unable to restart from where my batch left off. It always restarts from the beginning. Also, it creates a new task id for each time when restart the same task. Did I miss anything? Is there a way to restart with the same task id and resume the batch job where it was stopped? Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I am using XML for configuring batch job and steps. I am not using annotations.

[Task restart Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duDPS.jpg)

[Batch job executions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8ATD.jpg)

Comment: You should be getting a new task id each time (since it is a new run of the task).  Can you provide what the job parameters are each run?

Comment: I am now clear as per current executions that I get new task id. Only the question is why job is not starting from where it left off using record position.Here is the task definition:
task create smoketest_task_abc --definition "smoketest_app --datasourcename=abcsmoketest  --databasename=abcsmokedb --schemaname=abcsmokeschema --table=abcsmoketable"

Comment: I am seeing the following job parameters in the spring cloud dashboard for the above task  **"Job Parameters run.id(long)=2,--spring.cloud.task.executionid=26"**   I am seeing the same parameters values for all the executions for this task.

Comment: You are using a run id...that means you're getting a new job instance every time.  Why are you using one?

Comment: I am not manually setting this runId. It sets automatically. If this causing an issue, is there any configuration available to remove runId parameter?

Comment: Please provide your job configuration.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb295d5188e21d955dd1cae467bed499

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/908175f08e4f913b83e0462c630e5548

Comment: You're using a `RunIdIncrementer` on line 29 of the XML file (and the bean is configured at line 24).  Remove those and try again.

Comment: Thanks Michael!! I have applied your changes and executed on my local server. The task was executed successfully at first time. If I try to launch the same task again I am getting the following exeception **org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={-spring.cloud.task.executionid=3}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.**

Comment: A `'JobInstance` can only be run once to completion.

Comment: Thanks Michael!! What will be the best approach to execute the same job in regular interval? We have a requirement to launch a same job in every hour.

Comment: We should move this to the Spring Batch Gitter channel: https://gitter.im/spring-batch/Lobby